# HTML anchor send request but don't follow the link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where I have a link that sends data to a backend controller, it looks like this:
`http://url/backend/index.php?controller=someController&update=2&name="Test"`
This controller performs some operation on the transmitted data and returns a HTML view. However I have one special use case, where I want to trigger the data processing without following the redirect to the sent HTML response.
Is there a way to run the request and trigger the controller to process the data and stay on the same page/don't 'follow' the link? I thought of using `event.preventDefault()`, but I am not sure if this will also stop from making the controller process the request.

Comment: You need to show how you make this call. E.g. is this an Ajax call, if so: show it, including how you handle the result now. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: No, the call happens by requesting this URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could call event.preventDefault() and make the request via AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) inside your event listener.

Comment: Is there a possibility to convert a dynamic created URL into an AJAX call? The processing of the data is normally triggered by requesting this URL

Comment: You can retrieve the URL with this.href or event.target.href inside your event listener and use it to make a GET request

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make an AJAX request on a click event and get rid of the href property on the link itself.

So if this were your original code:

```
<a href="http://url/backend/index.php?controller=someController&update=2&name=Test">Test Link</a>
```

You would want to do something like this:

```
<a onclick="sendRequest">Test Link</a>

<script>

function sendRequest(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://url/backend/index.php?controller=someController&update=2&name=Test');

    xhr.send();

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda going on with what @sadq3377 was saying... but lets do this in an unobtrusive way...

```
<a id="some-link" href="http://url/backend/index.php?controller=someController&update=2&name='Test'"">Some link</a>
```

And then you can do some JavaScript like below

```
document.getElementById('some-link').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE HREF like use it for the ajax call
    var ajaxCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxCall.open('GET', this.href);
    ajaxCall.send();    
});
```

So at least you don't have any hardcoded items in your code...

---

To make this a little more extensible as @ItFreak is asking you can do this...

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    if( ev.target.getAttribute('data-ajax-link') !== null ){
        ev.preventDefault();
        // DO THE REST OF THE CODE FROM THE PREVIOUS EXAMPLE
    }
});
```

What this means is that all the links that you want to do that functionality will have to look like this...

```
<a id="some-link" data-ajax-link href="http://url/backend/index.php?controller=someController&update=2&name='Test'"">Some link</a>
```

Any link that has the 'data-ajax-link' attribute will go through this if statement and use this logic, all others will simply act like normal...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working fine.However, could you just show me how to handle multiple links? Is there a possibility to use this generalized function for any amount of links?

Comment: hey @ItFreak updated the answer so it does what you are looking for... there are many ways to do it as well but this is probably one of the most basic ways to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the link in another tab in that case. That way your original page stays the same.

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```